# Как выявить частотность слов в отфильтрованном DataFrame и выполнить их сортировку по частотности?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Имеется файл с поисковыми запросами ([cсылка на файл](https://yadi.sk/d/A-98NjcA3TktXp)).

Моя задача состоит в следующем:

1. Мне необходимо выбрать все запросы (в столбце "request"), которые связаны с темой телевидения (с этим я справился с помощью pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
    
frame = pd.read_csv('Log', header=0, sep = '\t')
frame.request[frame.request.str.contains('телевидение')]
```

2. Полученные данные необходимо сгруппировать по темам и посчитать доли основных групп в объеме запросов, связанных с телевидением.

Мои вопросы:

1. Для решения второго пункта я хочу получить слова, которые встречаются в запросах, связанных с телевидением и их частотность. Затем отсортировать их в порядке убывания частотности (Таким образом, я смогу понять какие слова, встречающиеся в этих запросах самые популярные и на основе этого пойму какие у меня основные группы). Подскажите каким образом это можно сделать?
2. Каким образом можно будет посчитать доли выявленных групп запросов? К примеру я захочу посчитать долю запросов связанных с телевидением, включающие слова "онлайн", "online" в объеме запросов, связанных с телевидением. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> выбрать все запросы (в столбце "request"), которые связаны с темой
>   телевидения

```
 reqs = frame.request[frame.request.str.contains('телевидение')]
```

> получить слова, которые встречаются в запросах, связанных с
>   телевидением и их частотность.

```
words = reqs.str.replace(r'http.*\/\?text=', '').str.extractall(r'(?u)\b(\w\w+)\b')
```

результат:

```
In [112]: words
Out[112]:
                         0
        match
15672   0      телевидение
        1       ростелеком
        2             flag
        3            e7954
15859   0         интернет
        1      телевидение
        2               от
        3              мтс
        4           личный
        5          кабинет
...                    ...
1299851 0        настоящее
        1      телевидение
        2             flag
        3          omx6227
1310317 0      телевидение
        1           онлайн
        2           client
        3           280836
1326007 0       леуганское
        1      телевидение

[1051 rows x 1 columns]
```

> Затем отсортировать их в порядке убывания частотности

```
freqs = words[0].value_counts()
```

результат:

```
In [113]: freqs
Out[113]:
телевидение     148
flag             49
онлайн           38
id               32
client           32
rl               30
интернет         20
мтс              13
эфир             12
прямой           12
               ...
благодаря         1
24                1
сервис            1
672               1
один              1
использовано      1
какое             1
grp               1
iptv              1
тыс               1
Name: 0, Length: 517, dtype: int64
```

> Каким образом можно будет посчитать доли выявленных групп запросов? К
>   примеру я захочу посчитать долю запросов связанных с телевидением,
>   включающие слова "онлайн", "online" в объеме запросов, связанных с
>   телевидением

```
res = freqs[freqs.index.isin(['online','онлайн','интернет'])] / len(words)
```

результат:

```
In [115]: res
Out[115]:
онлайн      0.036156
интернет    0.019029
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: 1. У меня при вводе первой команды отображается MemoryError.
2. Можете подсказать, где почитать подробнее о указанных вами командах. Я только начал знакомство с Python и пока не понимаю полный смысл указанных вами команд.

Comment: @deniska, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/ Но легче и быстрее пользоваться google'ом: https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+str.extractall&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr, https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+index+isin&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr, https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+value_counts&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr и т.д.

Comment: спасибо! Когда указал df = frame.request[frame.request.str.contains('телевидение')], затем words = df.request.str.replace(r'http.*\/\?text=', '').str.extractall(r'(?u)\b(\w\w+)\b'), получил следующую ошибку: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: @deniska, я исправил ответ...

Comment: а вы при считывание файла указывали кодировку? Потому что у меня после команды words = reqs.str.replace(r'http.*\/\?text=', '').str.extractall(r'(?u)\b(\w\w+)\b'), сейчас выводятся символы: е� и т.д.  Скрин: http://joxi.ru/823Wejpu6NnYP2

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` по умолчанию использует `UTF-8`. Я читал файл так: `df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')`

Comment: Я также, но у меня программа выводит символы "�" в результате.

Comment: вы используюте [тот же файл](https://yadi.sk/d/A-98NjcA3TktXp), что и я? Какая у вас версия Python и Pandas?

Comment: Файл использую тот же. Python 2.7, Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Попробовал в Python 3, все работает.

Comment: @deniska, да, это проблемы с Unicode в Python 2.x... Попробуйте так: `reqs.str.replace(r'http.*\/\?text=', '').str.decode('utf-8').str.extractall(r'(?u)\b(\w\w+)\b')`